# How can I inherit complex properties from the parent scope into my directive's isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

After reviewing AngularJS (and related) documentation and other stackoverflow questions regarding isolated scopes within directives, I'm still a little confused. Why can't I do a bi-directional binding between the parent scope and directive isolated scope, where the parent scope property is an object and not an attribute? Should I just use the desired property off `scope.$parent`? That seems wrong. Thanks in advance for your help.

The related fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ksevksev/PWdYZ/5/).

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div my-directive>{{test.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = {name:"name", value:"value"};
});

myApp.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {test: '='},
        template: '<div class="parent"><div>This is the parent Div.</div><div>Value={{test}}</div></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("scope.test=["+scope.test +"]");
            console.log("scope.$parent.test=["+scope.$parent.test.name+"]");
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For directives using an isolate scope, **attributes** are used to specify which parent scope properties the directive isolate child scope will need access to.  '=' provides two-way binding.  '@' provides "one-way strings".  '&' provides one-way expressions.

To give your directive (two-way binding) access to parent scope object property `test`, use this HTML:

```
<div my-directive test="test"></div>
```

It might be more instructive to use different names:

```
<div my-directive some-obj-prop="test"></div>
```

Then in your directive:

```
scope: { localDirProp: '=someObjProp'},
template: '<div ...>Value={{localDirProp}}...',
```

---

Isolate scopes do not prototypically inherit from the parent scope, so it does not have access to any of the parent scope's properties (unless '@' or '=' or '&' are used).  Using `$parent` is a way to still access the parent scope, but not via prototypical inheritance.  Angular creates this special `$parent` property on scopes.  Normally (i.e. best practice), it should not be used.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Given that the property I was trying to bind was an object, it didn't seem intuitive to reference it with an HTML attribute (which can only be strings). Also, since I was using the HTML simply as a place holder for where I wanted my directive to be, it didn't seem reasonable to me to use it to define properties I wished to sync between the scopes. Regardless, I think I get it now. I appreciate your answer. While the AngularJS documentation has some good points, can see serious room for improvement in explaining the mid-level concepts developers need to make code decisions.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it is rather weird for an HTML attribute's value to be the name of a (scope) object.

Comment: For those who may find this question helpful, here is the updated, working fiddle with Mark's suggestions implemented: http://jsfiddle.net/ksevksev/PWdYZ/

Comment: Good answer Mark. Is it a bit inaccurate to say that only '@' and '=' will give access to parent scope, will not '&' also do that?